# JQuery Mobile Showing Blank

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am building a JQuery Mobile web-app, and am running into an interesting problem. I have a listview, and when I click on one of the menu rows, page 2 loads as expected. However, when I click the back button, the page 1 page loads for a half a second, then page 2 comes back (without a transition).

Here is the code for the 2 pages:

```
<section id="more" data-role="page">
    <header data-role="header" data-position="fixed" class="AppHeader">
        <h1>More</h1>
    </header>

    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="false" id="moreList">
            <li><a href="#historyOfLandmarks" data-transition="slide"><h1>History of Boston Landmarks</h1></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</section>

<section id="historyOfLandmarks" data-role="page">
    <header data-role="header" data-position="fixed" class="AppHeader">
        <a href="#more" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse" data-icon="arrow-l" data-rel="back">Back</a>
        <h1>History of Boston Landmarks</h1>
    </header>

    <div data-role="content">
        <p>This is a list of National Historic Landmarks in Boston, Massachusetts.</p>
    </div>
</section>
```

JS Fiddle Does Not Illustrate the Problem: http://jsfiddle.net/jakechasan/66vbS/

Everywhere else, the problem appears: http://jakeserver.com/Apps/BostonLandmarks/B5/landmarks.html

I don't understand why JSFiddle does not illustrate the problem, however, the same file on my computer/server has this problem?

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your own CSS is responsible for this problem.

Edit this file: http://jakeserver.com/Apps/BostonLandmarks/B5/css/styles.css

And remove from the bottom:

```
.ui-page{
    display: block !important;
}
```

I have tested it successfully.

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer.